# Expectation and Variance of $\bar{X}/S$

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference

I got stuck on the following problem:

> Let $X_1 , \dots , X_n$ be iid from  $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. How can I obtain E$(\bar{X}/S)$, E$((\bar{X}/S)^2)$ and E$(\bar{X}^2)$, E$((\bar{X}^2)^2)$?

$\bar{X}$ is the sample mean and $S^2$ sample variance.

I've tried jacobian method for the first without success, and no idea on how to deal with the second.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What do $S$ denote for?

Comment: Furthermore why do you write down $E(\bar X/S)^2$ and $E(\bar X^2)^2...$ they are just the squares of the previous ones. Did you mean for the squares to be inside the expectations? For the second part, the sample mean for $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$-distributed samples has distribution $N(\mu,\sigma^2/n)$ (or just multiply it out and use what you know about the $X_i$)

Comment: First note that $\overline X$ is not correlated with $\left( X_1-\overline X, \ldots, X_n - \overline X \right),$ as may be seen be computing $\operatorname{cov}\left(\overline X, X_i - \overline X \right).$ Then recall that two linear combinations of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are uncorrelated only if they're independent if $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. normal. Use that two show that $\overline X$ and $1/S$ are independent. Then
$$
\operatorname E\left( \frac{\overline X} S \right) = \operatorname E\left( \overline X\right) \operatorname E\left( \frac 1 S \right).
$$

Comment: Finding $\operatorname E \overline X$ is easy. For the other expected value, do you know how to show that $(n-1)\dfrac{S^2}{\sigma^2} \sim \chi^2_{n-1} \text{?}$ If so, then you will need to find $$ \int_0^\infty \frac 1 {\sqrt u} f(u)\, du $$ where $f$ is the chi-square density. $\qquad$